# When reading, as via fread, a text file encoded as UTF-8, how can you determine how many bytes a character will take?

Tags: utf-8, ascii

If we want to represent more characters than ASCII allows, we can use Unicode, which
uses more bits than ASCII to represent some characters. One implementation of
Unicode, UTF-8, uses “variable-width encoding” to represent characters: characters can
be represented by either one, two, three, or four bytes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, a Unicode codepoint (what you call a character) can be represented in UTF-8 using 1..4 code units (8-bit bytes) each.  The bit pattern of the first code unit tells you how many code units are used:

[image]

Codepoints U+0000..U+007F use 1 code unit, where the sole code unit has its high bit set to `0`.

Codepoints U+0080..U+07FF use 2 code units, where the 1st code unit has its high 3 bits set to `110`.

Codepoints U+0800..U+FFFF use 3 code units, where the 1st code unit has its high 4 bits set to `1110`.

Codepoints U+10000..U+10FFFF use 4 code units, where the 1st code unit has its high 5 bits set to `11110`.

Given the 1st code unit of a UTF-8 encoded codepoint, you can mask its bits with a logical `AND` operator to determine which pattern is used, eg:

```c
int32_t readUTF8Char(FILE *f)
{
    uint8_t b;

    if (fread(&b, 1, 1, f) != 1) {
        // read error
        return -1;
    }

    if ((b & 0x80) == 0)
    {
        // 1 byte, use b as-is ...
        return b;
    }

    int32_t codePoint;
    int num = 0;

    if ((b & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
        // 2 bytes, read 1 more byte ...
        codePoint = b & 0x1F;
        num = 1;
    }
    else if ((b & 0xF0) == 0xE0) {
        // 3 bytes, read 2 more bytes ...
        codePoint = b & 0x0F;
        num = 2;
    }
    else if ((b & 0xF8) == 0xF0) {
        // 4 bytes, read 3 more bytes ...
        codePoint = b & 0x07;
        num = 3;
    }
    else {
        // malformed...
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        if (fread(&b, 1, 1, f) != 1) {
            // read error
            return -1;
        }
        if ((b & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
            // malformed
            return -1;
        }
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (b & 0x3F);
    }
    return codePoint;
}
```